# Creating an AST Tree in Java given another AST Tree

Tags: java, tree, sml

Currently, I'm working on representing an AST tree I have, written in SML, in Java so I can traverse it in Java whenever I want.

I'm wondering if I should just create a Node class in Java that has the data I want to represent, along with a an Array list (List) to represent the children for that specific node?  Then, I can have an ASTTree class that has only the root node.

I don't know if there is something more fancy I need to consider.

Any questions/comments will be greatly appreciated!

-Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do over that tree.

I usually implement it by creating a specific node for every kind of operation I would need, for example

```
ASTBinaryOperation implements ASTNode
{
  ASTNode left, right;
  Operator op;

  Result visit()
  {
    Result lr = left.visit();
    Result rr = right.visit();

    return op.apply(lr, rr);
  }
}
```

for a classical binary operator node, while I would use an `ArrayList` for example for declarations:

```
ASTDecl implements ASTNode
{
  String name;
  Type type;
  Value value;
}

ASTDecls implements ASTNode
{
  ArrayList<ASTDecl> declarations;
}
```

that is built up by the parser. So a root node would be something like:

```
ASTRoot {
  ASTDecls declarations;
  ASTFunctions functions;
}

ASTFunctions {
  ASTDecls args;
  ASTBody body;
  ..
}

ASTBody {
  ArrayList<ASTStatement> statements;
  ...
}
```

and so on.

Of course it depends what you will want to do, I used this approach to visit the AST to generate an intermediate code by recursively visiting the tree.. but storing whatever in an `ArrayList` will make you lose the specific behaviour and meaning of a single `ASTNode`.